# Django session data obtainable from models.py without key

Tags: python, django, session

I want to access a session variable from a model, in order to customize what gets shown in a template using `{{item.seller_email}}`. relevant code from models.py:

```
SESSION_STORE = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE).SessionStore
class Item(Action):
    def seller_email(self):
        seller = self.get_seller()
        session = SESSION_STORE()
        debug('session: %s' % vars(session))
        viewer = fetch(Client, email = session.get('client', None))
        administrator = viewer.is_admin() if viewer else False
        debug('viewer: %s, administrator: %s' % (viewer, administrator))
        if administrator:
            return seller.email
        else:
            return seller.anonymized[16:]
```

the answer here seems to say that this is not possible nor desired, but I lack the understanding of Django's session mechanism to be sure: [Access session / request information outside of views in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220484/access-session-request-information-outside-of-views-in-django)

this seems to indicate that the current session can be retrieved outside of views, though, just by not passing a key: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views, but I've tried it both that way and the above way with the same results: an "empty" session is created.

I'm sure there are other, better ways of doing this, and I will find one myself, but can someone familiar with Django internals explain why this is not possible?

Comment: Where do you call the `seller_email()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Because the model shouldn't know anything about session, that creates unnecessary entanglement(?) beetween different components and violation of MVC pattern.

What I suggest to do, is to call the function, specifying parameters needed to get a proper result, viewer object in this case.

If using the code in the question, how do you expect your model to work if it's used in a management command (where there is no http request and as a result no session) ?
Or from a celery job ?

Comment: I don't care about how it works in a management command, most of my code won't work that way.